# Django how to print data when using runserver

Tags: django

I have a dictionary data with how many players every user created:

**views.py**

```
def statistics(request):
    users = User.objects.all()
    data = dict()
    for user in users:
        players = Players.objects.filter(created__email=user.email).count()
        if players > 0:
            data[user.email] = players
            logger.info(data)
```

How can i print this dictionary in the console when i use runserver?
I have seen django loggers but i didn't understand them fully.

Comment: `print(data)` just prints the output into your command line running `python manage.py runserver`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should do like

```
import os

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_true': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugTrue',
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'filters': ['require_debug_true'],
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'mylogger': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': os.getenv('DJANGO_LOG_LEVEL', 'INFO'),
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
}
```

This will be printing to console when `DEBUG = True` (normally use runserver). Then you can do

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger("mylogger")
logger.info("Whatever to log")
```

Refer [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/logging/)

Comment: i've made everything you said here in the view i've added logger.info(data) but it isn't printing anything when i use runserver

Comment: i've eddited it

Comment: i have added `'propagate': True,`

Comment: Please tell your python version. Also try my updated answer. I have changed "mylogger" in two places.

Comment: python version 3.5.2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157466/discussion-between-nita-alexandru-and-itzmeontv).

Answer (score 3):

Setup logging in your django settings file:

```
import os

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': os.getenv('DJANGO_LOG_LEVEL', 'INFO'),
        },
    },
}
```

Then you can start logging in your view:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# Put the logging info within your django view
logger.info("Simple info")
```

See more information on the [Logging | Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/logging/) Documentation

**Good Luck !**

Comment: hi, i've added LOGGING in the settings.py file, i've imported logging, in the view i've added logger.debug(data) but it's not showing anything when i use runserver.

Comment: @NitaAlexandru Changing to logger.info("Simple info") shall fix problem

Answer (score 1):

Just add `print(players)` in loop and it will print results in terminal.

```
def statistics(request):
users = User.objects.all()
data = dict()
for user in users:
    players = Players.objects.filter(created__email=user.email).count()
    if players > 0:
        print(players)
        data[user.email] = players
        logger.info(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Andriy say you can use logging. It's get working out of the box.
If you want to pretty print dictionary you can use `pprint`

```
import pprint
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)

pp.pprint(yourdict)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your project is running on linux, it depends if runserver is on nohup. If not then all print statements will be visible on command line otherwise if its running on nohup then run the below command on command line.

```
tail -f nohup.out
```